# Render list item using FlatList in React Native and Firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, listitem, react-native-flatlist

Very new to react-native. I am not sure how data is passed into the Flatlist and how to render it. I am passing in the Restaurants array from firebase database to this.restaurantRef. listenForRestaurants is called when first rendered to push all the referenced items into an array called restaurants. Not quite sure how I should put the logic for rendering the list of restaurants from firebase database.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Component} from 'react'
import {
ScrollView,
Text,
FlatList,

} from 'react-native'
import firebase from '../firebase'
import ListItem from './ListItem'


export default class Location extends Component {

 constructor(props){
 super(props)
  this.restaurantRef = firebase.database().ref().
                      child('Restaurants')
  }


 listenForRestaurants(restaurantRef) {
  restaurantRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
   var restaurants = [];
   snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    restaurants.push({
     name: child.val().name,
      _key: child.val().key
    })
   })
  })
}
componentDidMount(){
 this.listenForRestaurants(this.restaurantRef)
}

_renderItem(item){
 return(
  <ListItem item={item} onPress={() => {}} />
 )
}
render(){
 return(
  <ScrollView>
   <FlatList
    data={this.restaurantRef}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
   />
  </ScrollView>
 )
 }
}

//This the ListItem component
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';


export default class ListItem extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onPress}>
    <View>
     <Text>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
    </View>
   </TouchableHighlight>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: First you don't need to put FlatList inside of ScrollView, second thing is that in the whole code snippet you posted, you haven't given an height, width, flex to any element, you need to provide them.

Comment: Thank you @ShubhnikSingh, I got it to render the items from firebase database. Now my next problem is to be able to click the each list item and to render a detailed page about that restaurant. How would I go about this?